# Qt UDpsocket working on same computer but not on two computers on same network

Tags: c++, qt, networking

I am able to send and receive to two different programs running on same computer. But not able to do the same when running them on different computers. Both computers are on same Local area network. I am working on windows 10.

```cpp
#include "communicationmanager.h"

communicationManager::communicationManager(int portNumber,int socketRole)
{
    //socketRole:0=Sender 1=Reciever
    //socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    PortNumber = portNumber;
    socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    if(socketRole == 1)
    {
        socket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost,PortNumber);
        connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(recieve()));
    }
}

communicationManager::~communicationManager()
{
    //delete socket;
}

void communicationManager::prepareMessage(QString command,QString message,int recieverID)
{
   
    Command = command;
    Message = message;
    recieverID = recieverID;
}

void communicationManager::send()
{
    QByteArray datagram;
    QDataStream out(&datagram, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_13);
    out<<Command<<Message<<recieverID;
    socket->writeDatagram(datagram, QHostAddress::LocalHost, PortNumber);

}

void communicationManager::recieve()//For recieving data
{
    qDebug()<<"recieve";
    QByteArray datagram;

    do
    {
        datagram.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
        socket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());
    } while (socket->hasPendingDatagrams());


    QDataStream in(&datagram, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QString command;
    QString message;
    int recieverID;
    in >>command>>message>>recieverID;
}
```

Comment: Hey there, you tagged this question with a few different languages, namely `C#`, `C++` and (implicitly) `Python`, please refrain from tagging your question with languages not related to your problem/ code as it will attract downvotes because people will see your question which can't necessarily help you out (me for example my C++ knowledge is basically non-existent). Remember you also don't need to add as many tags to your question as possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind to `QHostAddress::Any` in order to actually receive packets from outside the local machine. `QHostAddress::LocalHost` will only receive traffic from the same physical machine.

Comment: Do i have to use QHostAddress:: Broadcast at the sender.As you you told localhost is for same physical machine.I thought localhost is for same local network.

Comment: I tried QHostAddress:: Broadcast at sender.It worked.Thanks.